# Close a new Activity from a command the previous Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a `Activity A` where she start an `Activity B` that has a `VideoView`.

I need in the Activity A call Activity B and pass a `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener` listener for the video `Activity B` trigger commands on your order.

A required command would close the `Activity B`.

I can not implement `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener` in `Activity B` because in `Activity A` is a configuration screen that depending on the settings will be changed the `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener` codes for `VideoView`.

One of the possible commands to pass the `listener` is to close the `Activity B`. How can I tell the Activity B by Activity A within the listener to be closed?

I close with this activity since the finish and `onBackPressed` will be understood as commands for `Activity A` and not `Activity B`. 
I hope I Specified properly and made clear my doubt.

Comment: When activity A is in the backstack, it can't do anything.  It may not even exist.

Comment: You can use brodacast  in this case register the broadcast in activity which you want to close an

Comment: It sounds like it may be more advantageous for you to use a Fragment in place of Activity B, then Activity A can easily communicate to it through an interface and manage its lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll check.